# After rotation, sprite and rectangle position misaligned in Libgdx

Tags: android, opengl-es, libgdx, rotation

I have following code, where closely mapped sprite, rectangle and polygon is been rotated at same angle in libgdx.  After rotation rectangle is misaligned with the sprite. Although sprite is rotated when its drawn, the coordinates and dimensions  stay same after the rotation. This is not the case for rectangle.  Please see the code and results image below.

```
public void rotate(int angle){

    System.out.println("Before-recta x , y " + this.rectangle.getX() + " " + this.rectangle.getY() + " " + this.rectangle.getHeight() + " " + this.rectangle.getWidth());
    System.out.println("Before-sprite x , y " + sprite.getX() + " " + sprite.getY()+ " " + this.sprite.getHeight() + " " + this.sprite.getWidth());

    this.sprite.rotate(angle);
    this.rectangle = null;
    this.polygon.rotate(angle);
    this.rectangle = this.polygon.getBoundingRectangle();

    System.out.println("Afer-sprite x , y " + sprite.getX() + " " + sprite.getY() + " " + this.sprite.getHeight() + " " + this.sprite.getWidth());
    System.out.println("Afer-recta x , y " + this.rectangle.getX() + " " + this.rectangle.getY() + " " + this.rectangle.getHeight() + " " + this.rectangle.getWidth());
}
```

[image]

Comment: Is the origin position the same for both the sprite and the polygon?

Comment: Thanks for the response .I have tried setting         this.sprite.setOrigin(this.sprite.getWidth()/2, this.sprite.getHeight()/2); this.polygon.setOrigin(this.sprite.getWidth()/2, this.sprite.getHeight()/2);. That didn't resolve the issue. I printed polygon.getX and getY. They perfectly match sprite coordinates. But rectangle x, y varies only for 90 and 270 degree cases. at 180 and 0 they match precisely

Comment: Because the sprite and rectangle are different sizes the origin should be offset for the smaller rectangle so both origins are in the same world space.

Comment: Ohh sorry, do not worry about the smaller rectangle, I am talking about outer boundary rectangle. The table is showing the x,y of outer rectangle. Although drawing shows good alignment there x and y are different, as shown in the table. As u can see width and height is different too, which makes sense based on the rotation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the values for your rectangle the width is about 370 and the height is about 345. This is wider than it is taller. So when you rotate this you would expect it to be taller than it is wider. We'll do some quick match to see if what we're getting is correct:

We'll remove the width from the height to get the amount of extra space for both sides

> 370 - 346 = 24

Now we'll divide that by 2 as it's equally distributed to each side of the rectangle

> 24 / 2 = 12

we now take the original x position - 1/2 the extra value

> 268 - 12 = 256

And for the y position too

> 739 + 12 = 751

These match the values you are getting for x and y position for the rectangle so we know this is correct.

Now, if we do this for the Sprite you will see the value you are getting are not for the rotated sprite. The sprites before and after values are the same.

The reason for this is most likely that the sprite's x,y,w and h never change and instead a matrix is used to transform the image before rendering leaving the sprite with the original values throughout its lifetime.

Comment: Greate anaysis, But how do I move these objects on touch drag. If I use sprite x,y to shift rectangle its going to be wrong. Do u think I should use x,y of sprite, polygon and rectangle individually to shift by offset on touch drag. Also will overlap testing be correct for polygon if its not rotated

Comment: You could probably check the x and y difference of the sprite and polygon on click/touch down, then apply the drag x,y to sprite and the drag x+offset,y+offset to polygon. As for the overlap testing it should work as normal.